# Refreshing or Updating row with corresponding button click in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code to render details from *json* to my component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let wall of userWall">
    <td *ngFor="let item of keys" [hidden]="!item.visible" [ngStyle]="{'text-align':'left'}">
        <span *ngIf="item.fieldName=='walladdress' && wall[ item.fieldName]!=''">{{ wall[item.fieldName] }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="item.fieldName=='walladdress' && wall[ item.fieldName]==''">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="GenerateWall(wall.currid)">Generate</button>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="item.fieldName!='walladdress'">{{ wall[item.fieldName] }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now by clicking the button, I am creating a wall and send it back to front end. But I am a bit confused exactly how to place new generated wall to the corresponding row cell. It seems I am unable to refresh data after creating a wall. Here is the functions that I call:

```
GenerateWallet(currid){
    this.UserApi.GenerateWall(currid).subscribe(data => {
        getUserWall();
    })
}

getUserWall(){
    this.UserApi.GetUserWall().subscribe(data => {
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            this.userWall = data;
        }
    })
}

filteredCurrencies
  init() {
    var wall = this.userWall
    this.filteredCurrencies = []
    for (var currencyIndex in this.currencies) {
      var flag = true
      var currency = this.currencies[currencyIndex]
      for (var index in wall) {
        var wall = wall[index]
        if (wall.currid == currency.currid) {
          flag = false
          break;
        }
      }
      if (flag) {
        this.filteredCurrencies.push(currency)
      }
    }
  }
```

And the json data which is bound is like this:

```
[
  {
    "currid": 1,
    "currencyname": "XXXX",
    "currencyshortname": "XXX",
    "cursymbolurl": "xxxx",
    "walletacid": 1719,
    "accountid": 1044,
    "fundslocked": 0.0,
    "walladdress": "ffaab3be-1958-11e8-886a-8512c9ba4a42",
    "bal": "",
    "usdvalue": "",
    "availabal": ""
  },
  ...
]
```

I have no background of Angular4, not even AngularJS. One of the UIs was left in the middle and I just have to finish it. Just understanding the pattern and reusing the code smartly which is already created.

Comment: Please post the implementation of `getUserWall()`.

Comment: You sure about variable used in html `userWall`? Is it *userWall* or *userWallet*?

Comment: It is userwall, mistakely entered wallet

Comment: There is nothing related to compilation,

Comment: `this.UserApi.GetUserWall()` returns you a single wall or all walls for a user?

Comment: It returns json array, let me share you more code with you.

Comment: Can you share the returned *json*?

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Comment: It should work if `keys` is an array containing items like `[{visible: true, fieldName: "walladdress"}]`. Do you see walls rendered on page which are already saved?

Comment: everything is working fine, the button click etc. Just I have to refresh the page to see the result.

Comment: Try this, inside `getUserWall()` replace `this.userWall = data;` to `setTimeout(() => { this.userWall = data; });`

Comment: ok, here I was missing this keyword.. Instead it should read as this.getUserWall();

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: This refreshes entire table but not affected area.